# Resample only within the same day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing an asset price (OHLC asset data) such that its index is a datetime. The data shoud be sample in minutes but my dataset have some missing minutes.

[image]

To fill the missing data, I just used the function

```
df.resample("1Min").asfreq()
```

It fills correctly the minutes within one day, but since my dataframe contains data for different days, it usually fills the minutes until midnight of each day. I would like that, if one specific day contains data from 13:05pm to 20:50pm, it fills minute only between those times, i.e., do not exceed those bounds.

I looked at the documentation for the resample function and couldn't find how it can be done. I appreciate your help!

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with data for both days for see problem with expected output?

Comment: A very simple way would be to split the DataFrame by day, resample as you do now, then `pd.concat(dfs)` to recombine them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by days and chain [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) with [`Resampler.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.date).resample("1Min").first()
```